# How to check what the MySQL/MariaDB version is inside a config file?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The issue I run into is that when I run my database migrations I get an error when the charset is `utf8mb4` due to this line and some other indexes:

```
$table->string('taggable_type', 255)->index();
```

So, I thought that if I can modify the charset that is being used to utf8 in config/database.php by checking which MySQL version is used, the issue can be solved/worked around.

I was thinking about doing a raw query like:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"');
```

inside `config/database.php`. Now that error I receive is that

```
A facade root has not been set.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Yes, I have tried setting `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` inside the boot method of my AppServiceProvider and I have also tried `'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC'`, but I still receive that the specified key is too long which I believe might be due to MySQL 5.5 I believe.

Any help as to how I can check the MySQL version inside a config file or a hint to a different approach would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This got nothing to do with the mysql version, this issue is related to the character set chosen and limitations in mysql's innodb implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is available since 5.5.14.

1. Set `innodb_file_format=Barracuda`
2. Set `innodb_large_prefix=1`

This also requires the `'engine' => 'innodb row_format=dynamic'` which you've mentioned that you're already using. I am repeating it here for completeness.

Newer mysql versions (>=5.7.9) has a `innodb_default_row_format=dynamic` which can be used instead of the config change.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a real difference between `utf8` and `utf8mb4` (the former cannot represent a whole host of possible Unicode characters), you need to decide on whether you ***require*** `utf8mb4` or not. If you don't, and you want the option to support older MySQL versions, then simply settle on using `utf8`. If on the other hand you *do require* `utf8mb4` to guarantee the correct working of your app, then insist on using `utf8mb4` and ensure that the databases you're running on support it.